# Javascript debug no console error

Tags: javascript, debugging, runtime-error

My script dont run till the end. And stops due to errors. But there is no console error output.

```
alert("yo");
var go = "";
go.push(null);
alert("yo2");
```

- first alert works
- Tested with Chrome and Firefox
- No try catch blocks

Are there reasons for not showing up a console error, without knowing the whole code?

Comment: Are you using `try-catch` anywhere in your code? dose your code run partially? try putting `alert`s at different sections of your code to determine where the error happens (more or less) and post the code here.

Comment: alert("yo") is shown up, "yo2" not. No error. There is no try/catch.

Comment: Are you using it on a blank website or are there some libraries included as well? If there are libraries included, one of them might extend the prototype of the String object with a function called `push`.

Comment: the go.push was an example. There is no output on every error.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the error: `TypeError: Object has no method 'push'`
Im getting it in chrome console.

Comment: @bergman try it in a different browser. Maybe you have some tricky settings as I can see the error too

Comment: try adding to your code `console.log("some text")` can you see this at console?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the `push` method cannot be run on the variable `go`.
This is because it is of the type `String` and thus does have the `push` method available.

The push method is used to add items into an `Array` like this:

```
go = [];  // or you could use `go = Array()`;
go.push("A string");
go.push(null);
```

To output messages to the browser console, use `console.log` like this:

```
console.log("Some debug message");
console.log(go);  // outputs the above array
```

Comment: i can use console methods. But the error from my "it should throw a error example" wont come up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using try-catch:

```
try
{
    var my_app = new My_App();
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log("ERROR"+e);
}
```

Now i get the console output.